# How to stop Progress-bar when we stop Handler in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Hi I am new for android and in my app I am using Progress-bar for audio recording for this.

When I start recording I am updating the progress-bar and that's fine.

Here when I stop recording progress-bar not stop it's contiguously updating.

Please help me find out how to stop progress-bar when I stop recording.

```
private void startRecording() {
    try {
        handler = new Handler();
        recorderProgressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.recorder_progressBar);
        progressStatus = 0;
        // Start the lengthy operation in a background thread
        thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                    // Update the progress bar
                    if (handler != null) {
                        // Update the progress status
                        progressStatus += 1;
                        // Try to sleep the thread for 20 milliseconds
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        handler.post(runnable);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("it's calling ramakrishna");
        recorderProgressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
    }
};

private void stopRecording() {

    //Kill Background thread
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok let me try and tell you result

Comment: no even i initialize handler when Activity starts progressbar updating

Comment: please let me know solutiuon

Comment: i am very beginner please provide me solution with code

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the thread instead.

```
private void stopRecording() {
    //Kill Background thread
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }

    if (thread != null) {
        thread.stop();
    }
}
```

Or you may use `thread.interrupt()` as suggested here: [Do not use Thread.stop()](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/THI05-J.+Do+not+use+Thread.stop%28%29+to+terminate+threads).

Comment: UnsupportedOperationException i am getting

Comment: The link in my answer shows 3 ways of stopping a thread, nothing works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Define recorderProgressBar out of the method, then stop that if it's not null.